# I downloaded the etherum wallet, how do you back it up wallet.

Tags: mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, backup

I saw somewhere to copy your etherum key and email it to yourself. this way you have can find it. I would imagine this would be needed, say your computer gets stolen. Please if anyone has suggestions to protecting and backing up my wallet.